# Converting specific elements in a list of lists from a string to an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a structured list of lists in which each element is a string. I want to convert certain (known index, always the same) elements in this list of lists to integers. I've tried using list comprehension or the `isdigit()` method (there are no negative elements) but can't figure it out.

```
list_of_lists = [['spam','1','toast'], ['bacon','5','eggs'], ['juice', '8', 'tea']]
new_breakfast_list = [[int(element) for element in row] for row in list_of_lists]
```

The above code understandably gives `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'spam'` when it tries converting the first element. I want to either ignore the error and move forward to the next element or maybe specifically loop over something like `list_of_lists[i][1]` so I can get:

```
print(new_breakfast_list)
[['spam', 1, 'toast'], ['bacon', 5, 'eggs'], ['juice', 8, 'tea']]
```

Comment: What about using a list of dictionaries instead of a list of lists? Your inner elements seem to be structured, which would be more suitable to using a dictionary or even creating a class.

Comment: Is the element you want to convert always in the same position for each list?

Comment: Yes, using a class or a dictionary would probably be more suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list comprehension is almost correct, you just need to check using `isdigit()` in the inner loop, and use `int(element)` or just `element` depending on the value if `isdigit`.

```
new_breakfast_list = [[int(element) for element in row if element.isdigit() else element] for row in list_of_lists]
```

Alternatively, as you know integer elements occur at index `1`, you could use:

```
for element in list_of_lists:
    element[1]=int(element[1])
```

As you know the indexes you want to change, you should use this method as it saves needlessly looping through every element.

Comment: Agree with this:  If you know for sure that each inner list has 3 elements, then why loop over them...just index them. (Maybe that's not Pythonic?)

Comment: the `for` loop is maybe the simplest way to do it. Not every problem must be solved with list comprehension.

Comment: I was confused by that to call the correct element I needed a two-digit index e.g. `print(list_of_lists[1])` gives `['bacon', 5, 'eggs']` not `5`. If you write it like `for row in list_of_lists:` \n `row[1]=int(row[1])` it makes more sense to me. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Outside of the loop, you would need `list_of_lists[x][1]` to get the desired element as `list_of_lists` is 2-dimensional. However, in the loop, `element` is a list e.g on the first iteration, `element` would be `['spam', 1, 'toast']`. As this is only a 1-dimensional list, you only need to index it using `element[1]`

Comment: Try `new_lunch_list`

Answer (score 2):

since you're dealing with positive integers you can check if the string has only digits in it and convert or not using a ternary.

```
list_of_lists = [['spam','1','toast'], ['bacon','5','eggs'], ['juice', '8', 'tea']]
new_breakfast_list = [[int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in row] for row in list_of_lists]
```

yields:

```
[['spam', 1, 'toast'], ['bacon', 5, 'eggs'], ['juice', 8, 'tea']]
```

2 downsides though:

- it tries to convert all items, even though only the 2nd one is an integer
- it doesn't handle negatives (if you need them)

note: there's a cumbersome/not so performant way to handle the general positive/negative/starting with space integer case, use it only it you have to! otherwise the wim answer with `try/except` is better

```
new_breakfast_list = [[int(element) if element.strip().isdigit() or (element.strip()[0]=="-" and element.strip()[1:].isdigit()) else element for element in row] for row in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: `isdigit` is a bad way to check whether or not `int(element)` will work.

Comment: agreed but in that case you're dealing with number of elements, which cannot be negative, or I wouldn't have answered that.

Comment: OK, I missed that.  Removed downvote.

Comment: fair enough. I know there is no easy way to deal with negative/positive in list comprehensions without making them overly complex...

Answer (score 1):

Just define your own little helper function, something simple like:

```
def maybe_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val
```

Now you can use that in any kind of comprehension you want.  It will continue to work in some cases where using an `str.isdigit` check fails (e.g. whitespace in the string, negative numbers, etc).

If the structure of the data is reliable, don't bother with this stuff at all.  Just do a simple list-comp:

```
>>> [[x, int(n), y] for x, n, y in list_of_lists]
[['spam', 1, 'toast'], ['bacon', 5, 'eggs'], ['juice', 8, 'tea']]
```

Comment: you should re-add the part about negative numbers. Most people overlook that part and your function looks cumbersome.

Comment: OK, added it back.

Comment: and your listcomp is good since it doesn't try to convert the other items.